# What is the actual `texmf.cnf` file of a docker TeX Live installation?

Tags: texlive, texmf.cnf, docker

(Disclaimer: I am new to Docker.)

I'd like to (locally) use TeX Live through `docker`. Running:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/workdir danteev/texlive pdflatex test
```

works nicely.

The trouble is about customized settings regarding `TEXMFHOME` and `openout_any`. Changing these settings involves `texmf.cnf` and the one known by `docker` seems to be the one of my ordinary TeX Live installation:

```bash
$ kpsewhich texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/workdir danteev/texlive kpsewhich texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf
```

But these settings of my ordinary and the docker TeX Live installations are not the same ones:

```bash
$ kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/bitouze/texmf
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/workdir danteev/texlive kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME
/root/texmf
```

and:

```bash
$ kpsewhich --var-value openout_any
r
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/workdir danteev/texlive kpsewhich --var-value openout_any
p
```

Hence my question: what is the actual `texmf.cnf` file of this docker TeX Live installation?

Comment: the path reported by kpsewhich is the /usr/local in your docker container as far as I can tell

Comment: you could edit them and save as a new container or have a texmf.cnf in your current directory or just set the values in the shell environment rather than in texmf.cnf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The path reported by `kpsewhich` is indeed the `/usr/local` in the docker container. That's not easy to find! For me, it is currently `/home/bitouze/docker/overlay2/900efc007a62210dbcbdaf4a820e4f39de93fa26893e1a2b6128bbdb61cb6005/diff/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf.cnf`. Unfortunately, though `openout_any` is now set to `r` for the docker TeX Live installation, files in parent directories are not found.

Comment: You are not supposed to "find" files in the docker container on your local filesystem, that is the whole point, it is it's own sandboxed container with its own filespace you have a new tex installation installed in that file system.

Comment: you have mounted the the current directory as `/workdir` in the docker filesystem so that directory has no parents there are no files to find above that. Pehaps you wanted to mount the parent of the current directory if that has files that you want to see in docker?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I mount the parent of the current directory (`docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/absolute/path/to/the/parent/directory danteev/texlive pdflatex test`), the `test.tex` file of the current directory isn't found.

Comment: no that is the wrong way round, that has mounted the current directory as /absolute/path/to/the/parent/directory in docker, you want  `$pwd/..:/workdir` then you probably need to cd into /workdir/currendir before running pdftex. use `bash` rather than `pdflatex` in the docker run then you get a longer lasting run and you can cd and ls and see what the filesystem looks like within teh container and then run pdflatex. Once you have the files mounted in the right  place go back to calling pdftex directly

Comment: How to  `cd` into `/workdir/currendir` before running `pdftex`? And I don't understand `. use `...

Comment: sorry the backtick got misplaced, look now, the . was end of sentence. I mean instead of pdftex start up docker with bash then you can cd around the file system use ls to check all files are available then cd to the right place and run pdftex. If that works you can specify the same on the docker commandline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124745/discussion-between-denis-bitouze-and-david-carlisle).